# waiting IObservable to get all elements error

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have this class:

```
public class TestService
{
     public IObservable<int> GetObservable(int max)
     {
         var subject = new Subject<int>();
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                               {
                                   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                                   {
                                       subject.OnNext(i);
                                   }
                                   subject.OnCompleted();

                               });
         return subject;
     }
}
```

I wrote a test method for this as well:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestServiceTest1()
{
   var testService = new TestService();
   var i = 0;
   var observable = testService.GetObservable(3);
   observable.Subscribe(_ =>
   {
      i++;
   });          
   observable.Wait();
   Assert.AreEqual(i, 3);
}
```

But sometimes I get the error: **Sequence contains no elements** in method Wait().

I propose that my IObservable is completed before test reaches the *observable.Wait()* line. 
How can I avoid this error?

Comment: While my knowledge of Rx isn't great, I have watched some of the videos provided on Channel 9, and it seems to me that `TestService.GetObservable` would be better represented by `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Range(0, max, System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.NewThread)`

Comment: @DoomMuffins. The matter is the right way of waiting IObservable. Not proper implemetation of GetObservable method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the basic problem in this code is that an `IObservable` **represents a contract of how to observe something.**

In this case, the `GetObservable` method is not just returning a contract, it is performing work (with TPL) right away. This does not make sense if you consider that you can subscribe multiple times to the same `IObservable` instance (which is in fact happening in the sample code, as you're subscribing a first time with `Subscribe` and another with `Wait`). *This single distinction was the biggest stumbling block for me in learning Rx.*

I would instead implement the method like this (and avoid altogether using `Subject<>`, since it is not the preferred way of creating an Observable):

```
public class TestService
{
     public IObservable<int> GetObservable(int max)
     {
         return Observable.Create<int>((IObserver<int> observer) =>
                               {
                                   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                                   {
                                       observer.OnNext(i);
                                   }
                                   observer.OnCompleted();
                               });
     }
}
```

There are also interesting overrides to `Observable.Create` which provide more flexibility.

Comment: In order to properly test Rx queries, you should use a `TestScheduler` from the [Rx-Testing NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Rx-Testing/). You can schedule work inside the `Observable.Create` lambda, and in your test, you just check which events were recorded by the `TestScheduler`.

Comment: Great answer Pedro. You will also find that Observable.Range(0,100,TaskPoolScheduler.Default) is the correct implementation of what takayoshi is trying to achieve (as he was trying to introduce concurrency). However concurrency and unit tests are not good friends, favor the TestScheduler.

Comment: I completely agree. I'm actually co-authoring a BDD unit test framework which should make it much more straightforward to unit test Rx code, providing guidance on how to test asynchronous code while maintaining great readability and maintainability. I'm looking forward to having the documentation at a point where I can start showing it to the community.

Comment: Cool. I am interested to see how this is different to normal unit testing or any other test framework -->Do we need another framework :-(