# How do I get a list of strings from an observable.Subscribe function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minio

I got the C# .net core [ListObjectsAsync example](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/blob/master/Minio.Examples/Cases/ListObjects.cs) working for Minio: 
, but how do I capture the results into a List instead of publishing to a console?

```
using System;
using Minio.DataModel;

namespace Minio.Examples.Cases
{

    class ListObjects
    {
        // List objects matching optional prefix in a specified bucket.
        public static void Run(Minio.MinioClient minio,
                                     string bucketName = "my-bucket-name",
                                     string prefix = null,
                                     bool recursive = false)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Running example for API: ListObjectsAsync");
                IObservable<Item> observable = minio.ListObjectsAsync(bucketName, prefix, recursive);

                IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(
                    item => Console.WriteLine("Object: {0}", item.Key),
                    ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex),
                    () => Console.WriteLine("Listed all objects in bucket " + bucketName + "\n"));

                // subscription.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Bucket]  Exception: {0}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried modifying the Subscribe function so that it would add the names to a list instead of print them to a console:

```
IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(
item => names.Add(item.Key), 
ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex), 
() => Console.WriteLine("Listed all objects in bucket "  
+ bucketName + "\n" + "count:" + names.Count +"\n"));
```

it prints 7, but if I print names.Count outside of Subscribe it prints 0;

This is What I want to do:

```
List<Item> myList = new List<Item>(observable.ToList().Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("do something"),
  ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex),
  () => Console.WriteLine("Done" + "\n"));
```

But observable returns an IDisposable so that's not possible. How do I go from an observable to a List ? or how do I collect the data so I can pass it into an asp.net core view?

This works - using Wait just like svek suggested. Didn't realize the syntax until I read this: [waiting IObservable to get all elements error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155094/waiting-iobservable-to-get-all-elements-error)

```
List<Item> names = new List<Item>();

IDisposable subscription = observable.ToList().Subscribe(
  x => names.AddRange(x),
  ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex), 
  () => Console.WriteLine("Done" + "\n") );
observable.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("out of subscribe count:" + names.Count + "\n");
subscription.Dispose();
return names;
```

Comment: You can also do `observable.ToList().Subscribe(` which changes the observable from producing zero or more `T` to producing a single `IList<T>` (with zero or more elements).

Comment: If I use ToList() the data is still "trapped" inside of the observable function. How do I get a List<T> that contains the data I'm intersted in? or Maybe the right way to word it, how do I convert from an Observable<T> to a List<T>?

Comment: Try `.ToList().Wait()`. That isn't ideal, however, as it is a blocking call (which you did ask for), but you should really use `.Subscribe(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I find your code a bit harder to read than what I am accustomed to. In regards to your topic, *How do I get a list of strings from an observable.Subscribe function* the **code itself is valid**

> The reason why you are getting `0` when you try and print `names.Count` is likely because you are not waiting for the asynchronous operation of the `Observable <T>.Subscribe()` method to complete.

To help you understand the syntax of your code, see this example:

```
IObservable<int> source = Observable.Range(1, 10);
IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}", x),
    ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex.Message),
    () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));

Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to unsubscribe...");
Console.ReadLine();
subscription.Dispose();
```

Which can be rewritten to use the `Observer` type like so:

```
IObservable<int> source = Observable.Range(1, 10);
IObserver<int> observer = Observer.Create<int>(
    x => Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}", x),
    ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex.Message),
    () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));        
IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe(observer);

Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to unsubscribe...");
Console.ReadLine();
subscription.Dispose();
```

The above refactoring will help clarify the solution far more. As you can see the parameters that were used in the first code block is actually calling the `Observer.Create<T>()` method.

[Observer.Create Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx) looks like this:

```
public static IObserver<T> Create<T>(
    Action<T> onNext,
    Action<Exception> onError,
    Action onCompleted
)
```

That is why this will properly return the count when you use:

```
// OnCompleted
() => Console.WriteLine("Listed all objects in bucket " 
          + bucketName + "\n" + "count:" + names.Count +"\n"));
```

because it is properly waiting for the sequence to complete before doing the action of displaying the message to the console.

**To solve your problem, you simply need to wait for your asynchronous `Subscribe` operation to complete first before trying to enumerate it.**

---

*Note:*
*The code examples from above were taken from MSDN and can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx).*

Comment: where do I put the wait? nothing I'm trying is working. Including observable.ToList().Subscribe and observable.Aggregate

Comment: @MattLengenfelder - would you mind posting another question and then share the link in the comments? I'm afraid this answer is quite lengthy as-is. Otherwise, you could read about how to implement the `Observer` pattern, note the 2nd refactored code block (above) as a guide.

Comment: I got it working, thanks! I just needed to add observable.Wait(); before printing names.count() I didn't know the wait syntax, I kept trying 
wait observable.subscribe 
and other things that didn't work, but obeservable.wait() works.